# Приложение по просмотру только одного сайта на WebView

Tags: java, android, html5, ide, webview

Всем доброго вечера.
Назрел вопрос. Как вообще создать приложение для андроид для просмотра только одного сайта. То есть мини-браузер который только одну страницу и открывает,видел некоторые примеры. Где вообще пишется код для `WebView`? Есть ли ещё темы или примеры создания вплоть до выбора IDE и тд. Да,вопрос глупый, поэтому извините.

Comment: Вот хороший пример того что вам надо:
[WebView - создай свой браузер](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/mybrowser.php)

Answer (score 1):

Создаете проект в Android Studio с Empty Activity. В корень layout-а кладете `WebView`, в методе `OnCreate(...)` активити находите этот виджет и перенаправляете `WebView` на необходимый сайт:

```
mWebview.loadUrl("http://www.foo.bar");
```

В первом приближении все.

P.S. Если мне не изменяет память, то Google Play не пропустит подобное приложение. *Да и зачем оно вообще нужно?!*